# Comparing an HTML value to a jquery input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, jquery-selectors

I feel like I'm missing something small, but I can't seem to make this work.  I am validating a form where a user is allowed to change their email, and among other things want to confirm that they have not re-entered the same email that they already have.

I've played around a lot trying to pull the value of the p with id="originalemail", but I can't seem to get it in a form that, when compared to the value entered, reflects that the strings are identical.  Any help would be hugely appreciated.

For the sake of simplicity, I've trimmed the function to only validate based on whether or not the entered new email matches the currently existing (original) email:

JS/jquery:

```
<script>
function validateEmailChange()
{
    // set comparison
    var originalemail=document.getElementById("originalemail").innerHTML;
    var newemail=document.forms["emailform"]["emailnewemail"].value;

    if (newemail == originalemail)
    {
        $('#emailnewemailoff').html("Same as current email address");
        $('#emailconfirmationoff').html("");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
// show the user's current email
<p id="originalemail"><?= htmlspecialchars($user[0]["email"]) ?></p>

<form id="emailform" name="emailform" onsubmit="return validateEmailChange()" 
              action="email.php" method="post">

<input id="emailnewemail" name="emailnewemail" placeholder="New Email" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" value="Change Email" class="btn"/>
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created jQuery that evaluates when the user moves off the email input field (`$('#emailnewemail').blur()`, and it compares the values case-insensitive (`.toLowerCase()`) too, so that 'my@email.com' is recognized to be the same as 'my@EMAIL.COM'.

```
$('#emailnewemail').blur(function() {
    if ($('#originalemail').text().toLowerCase() === $('#emailnewemail').val().toLowerCase()) {
        $('#emailnewemailoff').html("Same as current email address");
        $('#emailconfirmationoff').html("");
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#emailnewemailoff').html("Not the same email address");
    }
});
```

See http://fiddle.jshell.net/jhfrench/EZp6R/ for a working example.

Comment: You might want to check for spaces too...you can use `.trim()`: `if ($('#originalemail').text().trim().toLowerCase() === $('#emailnewemail').val().trim().toLowerCase())`

Comment: Thanks so much, the trim was actually the key, I'd failed to note above that the paragraph was wrapping (you can see I answered my own question above).  Again, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could try `if( $('#originalemail').text() == $('#emailnewemail').val() )`

Comment: And an **} else {** seems to be missing.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I actually have an else in the actual statement, just left it out here.  I actually figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try extracting the values using jQuery. I'm not sure why you decided to fall back to native JavaScript for these two lines -

```
var originalemail=document.getElementById("originalemail").innerHTML;
var newemail=document.forms["emailform"]["emailnewemail"].value;
```

Using jQuery, these lines would look something like this -

```
var originalemail = $("#originalemail").text();
var newemail = $("#emailnewemail").val();
```

### [Here is a little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sDjDd/)

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't doing the trick, it still fails to compare the two, would love any other thoughts you may have.

Comment: So this wasn't working, but I figured out the problem (and it turns out I didn't demonstrate it above).

Comment: I was failing to have the text inside the originalEmail box in such a way that it didn't include spaces, so I had:

<p ______________________>
    *originalemail*</p>

Comment: It failed to show up there (and I'm being a moron with the enter button), but what I'm trying to say is I had the innerHTML on a new line, and as a result leading spaces were included in the value, making it so my == statement wouldn't work.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my issue was that I was wrapping the

line, and as a result leading zeroes were being included.  It looked like the below.  Fixing this solved the problem, thanks all for your help, and I apologize for the bad question posting (still new to coding, so syntax like this still gets me)

```
<p id="originalemail">
    <?= htmlspecialchars($user[0]["email"]) ?></p>
```

Comment: as Jeromy French pointed out below, the .trim() function can be used to eliminate the leading spaces created by the above